# The word "pour" in this context

Tags: word-usage, phrasal-verbs

1. Pour the oil into the bottle.
2. Pour over the oil into the bottle.

As I am not a native speaker, using the word "pour" is difficult to me.

Are these two sentences correct, or should I use something else in this context?

And what can be the possible phrasal verbs with the word "pour".

Answer (score 3):

- Pour the oil into the bottle. Pour something into something
- Pour oil over something. Pour oil over or on something. [not really phrasal]

Phrasal verb, pour out:

**Pour out** the liquid before using the product. [get rid of it before using the product]

The people **poured out** or poured into the stadium. [pour in or pour out of a place, compares people to a liquid.

Rainwater was pouring out of the drain.

pour out/into= coming into or out of a place like a wave of liquid

Answer (score 1):

The first is correct.

You might say "pour over the oil" as a rephrasing of "pour the oil over" where the direct object is obvious from context, such as in a recipe. But when talking about pouring oil, *over* and *into* are words that would generally be expected to perform the same role, indicating the manner or direction of the pouring.